# Converting missing values to NA within sapply function

Tags: r, json

I want to import json data from some kind of fitness tracker in order to run some analysis on them. The single json files are quite large, while I am only interested in specific numbers per training session (each json file is a training session).

I managed to read in the names of the files & to grab the interesting content out of the files. Unfortunately my code does obviously not work correctly if one or more information are missing in some of the json files (e.g. distance is not availaible as it was an indoor training).

I stored all json files with training sessions in a folder (=path in the code) and asked R to get a list of the files in that folder:

```
json_files<- list.files(path,pattern = ".json",full.names = TRUE) #this is the list of files

jlist<-as.list(json_files)
```

Then I wrote this function to get the data im interested in from each single file (as reading in all the content for each file exceeded my available RAM capacity...)

```
importPFData <- function(x)
  {
  testimport<-fromJSON(x)
  sport<-testimport$exercises$sport
  starttimesession<-testimport$exercises$startTime
  endtimesession<-testimport$exercises$stopTime
  distance<-testimport$exercises$distance
  durationsport<-testimport$exercises$duration
  maxHRsession <- testimport$exercises$heartRate$max
  minHRsession <- testimport$exercises$heartRate$min
  avgHRsession <- testimport$exercises$heartRate$avg
  calories <- testimport$exercises$kiloCalories
  VO2max_overall <- testimport$physicalInformationSnapshot$vo2Max
  return(c(starttimesession,endtimesession,sport,distance,durationsport,
         maxHRsession,minHRsession,avgHRsession,calories,VO2max_overall))
  }
```

Next I applied this function to all elements of my list of files:

```
dataTest<-sapply(jlist, importPFData)
```

I receive a list with one entry per file, as expected. Unfortunately not all of the data was available per file, which results in some entries having 7, other having 8,9 or 10 entries.
I struggle with getting this into a proper dataframe as the infomation is not shown as NA or 0, its just left out.

Is there an easy way to include NA in the function above if no information is found in the individual json file for that specific detail (e.g. distance not available --> "NA" for distance for this single entry)?

**Example (csv) of the content of a file with 10 entries:**

"","c..2013.01.06T08.52.38.000....2013.01.06T09.52.46.600....RUNNING..."
"1","2013-01-06T08:52:38.000"
"2","2013-01-06T09:52:46.600"
"3","RUNNING"
"4","6890"
"5","PT3608.600S"
"6","234"
"7","94"
"8","139"
"9","700"
"10","48"

**Example (csv) for a file with only 7 entries (columns won´t macht to Example 1):**
"","c..2014.01.22T18.38.30.000....2014.01.22T18.38.32.000....RUNNING..."
"1","2014-01-22T18:38:30.000"
"2","2014-01-22T18:38:32.000"
"3","RUNNING"
"4","0"
"5","PT2S"
"6","0"
"7","46"

Comment: Hi @AMWiedl, you can add an ifelse statement inside your function like `sport <- ifelse(length(testimport$exercises$sport) > 0, testimport$exercises$sport, NA)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for (simple & efficient)!